# How to create a Modal that has multiple steps?

Tags: react-native

I would like to create a Modal that pops up from the bottom of the screen (similar to Payment Request API) where a user would fill a form and then presses continue, and the modal scrolls to the next step (i.e the modal remains but next step slides in). Is there any plugin that already exists, or has this been done before? (I'm not sure of the limitations of React Native). Just a side note I know how to make a modal popup from the bottom of the screen but not sure how to make the modal slide horizontal in steps.

Comment: Simply set a horizontal ScrollView as content of the Modal with scroll disabled. Then scroll programmatically when each step is completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a step in your state

```
this.state={step:'intial'}
```

and in your render method use step to find out which model to show

```
<Modal open={true}>
   (this.state.step=='intial'?<view></view>:null>

   (this.state.step=='second'?<view></view>:null>
</Modal>
```

you can use animation to make work better